# Accessing and setting objects in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a class in Rails 3.2 we'll call Foo that has_one of another class called Bar (both ActiveRecords) like so:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name
end


class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bar

  def bar_name
    if bar
      bar.name
    else
      nil
  end
end
```

When I try to call bar_name I get a mysql error like so:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'bar.foo_id' in 
 'where clause': SELECT  `bar`.* FROM `bar`  WHERE `bar`.`foo_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

My question is why is Rails trying to select bar by foo's id when I clearly want bar by foo's attribute of bar_id.

Please let me know if this needs more explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `has_one` association foreign key is placed in the `referenced model(Bar)` and not in `declaring model(Foo)`. So, in your case rails expects foreign key in `Bar` model as `Bar.foo_id`. This is the reason for the query in the error message.

You should use `belongs_to` when you want the foreign key in the `declaring model`, use `has_one` if you want it on the other model.

If you want foreign_key in Foo as bar_id then,

You could either go for a `belongs_to :bar` In Foo model

Or

A `has_one :foo` in Bar model.

Comment: Huh...that worked but the wording seems a bit counter-intuitive to me considering in the database foo 'has_one' key referencing bar and bar has no knowledge of foo. Well anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your relations backwards. In your case, `class Foo` should have `belongs_to :bar` rather than `has_one :bar`.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar

  ...

end
```

The table in the relation that has the key of the other table always uses `belongs_to` in the association. For more information on `belongs_to` associations (and associations in general), see:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association